# Is there any difference between "along" & "by" the river"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

Is there any difference in meaning between those two sentences concerning the use of (along) vs. (by)?

> 1- Cities must have water, and so they are often built **along rivers**.
>
> 2- Cities are built in safe, suitable places, such as **by rivers**.

*Can they be equally replaced?*

> 1- Cities must have water, and so they are often built ***by rivers***.
>
> 2- Cities are built in safe, suitable places, such as ***along rivers***.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to thoroughly split hairs, I suppose we could come up with a slight difference.

- Any city that is built **along** a river can also said to be **by** a river.
- However, not every city that is built **by** a river can be accurately described as being **along** a river.

Consider this map:

[image]

Both cities are **by** the river (we could also say they are **on** the river), but one could argue that the northern city is built **along** the river, while the southern city is built more **near** the river than **along** it.

However, most of time time, people won't think that much about this subtle difference. And nobody would argue that the northern city is not **by** the river, because clearly it is.

Also, in a practical sense, most cities probably take up enough riverfront land that it would be very hard to find an example of a city that would be considered **by** a river but not **along** the river.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes in this case along and by are interchangeable**

**Along** or **alongside** can be used when the meaning is **next to**.

**by** can be used as a preposition, adverb meaning **near** or **beside**(in distance)

If you need to reference all are available in the Cambridge English Dictionary online [Link to C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/by)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there can be a difference, but note that they can be used synonymously.

According to the Merriam-Webster ESL Learners Dictionary, which is found [here](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/along):

> **along**
>
> 1 
>   : in a line matching the length or direction of (something)
>
> *We walked along the beach.*
>       *We walked along (the side of) the road.*
>       *The chairs were lined up along the wall.*
>       *The ship sailed along the coast.*
>
> 2 
>   : at a point on (something)
>
> *They have a house along [=alongside] the river.*
>      *We drove to Boston and we stopped along the way for lunch.*
>
> **by**
>
> 1 
>   : close to or next to (something or someone) : near
>
> *She was standing by [=beside] the window.*
>       *His wife was sitting by him.*
>       *They have a house by the lake.*

So, *along rivers* can mean *matching the length of rivers*, and *by* can mean *near*. Your example sentences cannot be equally replaced.